# Android Google maps locations icons filtering

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with Google Maps where I need to hide some icons that are shown automatically on the map such as museums, bus stops, parks etc.
I am having problems searching the documentation for this because I do not even know how these marker icons are called in Google Maps. I would highly appreciate any information you have that can help me find a solution, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) for this.

Would need to do poi.park visiblity turn off.

You can see all of the supported places type [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types).

To see how to use Places API in Android, you can check this [link](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html) out.

Comment: I have not tried it yet but looking at the documentation it really seems to be the solution to my problem. Thank you very much for your help